# Stored Procedure Result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which calls other stored procedures and then returns a message. However, the SP is not working as intended:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID int,
    @UN nvarchar(30),
    @PW nvarchar(30),
    @Message nvarchar(50) out
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Variables
    Declare @ValidUser nvarchar(75);
    Declare @Current nvarchar(50);
    Declare @Log bit = 0;
    Declare @LogDateTime datetime2 = getdate();

    Execute @ValidUser = sp_UserValidation @ID, @UN, @PW, @ValidUser;
    --sp_UserValidation returns 'Success'

    If @ValidUser = 'Success'
        Begin
            -- 2) Validate Account
            Execute @Current = sp_ValidateCurrent @ID, @Current;
            --sp_ValidateCurrent returns 'Account is current'

            If @ACurrent = 'Account is current'
                Begin
                    Set @Message = 'Success';
                End
            Else
                Begin
                    If @Current = 'Grace'
                        Begin
                            Set @Message = 'Grace';
                        End
                    Else
                        Begin
                            If @AccountCurrent = 'Not Billing'
                                Begin
                                    Set @Message = 'Success';
                                End
                            Else Set @Message = 'Failure'
                        End
                End
        End
    Else Set @Message = 'Not valid.';

    Select @Message;
END
```

According to my logic, the @Message should equal 'Success', however 'Not valid' is being returned. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know. Thank you.

Here is the logic for sp_UserValidation:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UserValidation] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ID int,
@UN nvarchar(30),
@PW nvarchar(30),
@Output nvarchar(50) out
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @UserCount int = 0;
Declare @AccountLocked bit = 1;
Declare @FailedAttempts int = 4;
Declare @MaxAttempts int = 3;
Declare @LastLogin datetime2;

Set @Output = 'Error: Please try again';

-- 1) Check that Account Code/UserName/Password combination exists
Select @UserCount = count(*) from tblUSER where ID = @AID AND UserName = @UN AND Password = @PW;

If @UserCount = 1
Begin
    -- 2) Check that the User Account is not locked
    -- 2.a) Get maximum allowed attempts
    Select @MaxAttempts = Value from tbl_sysTABLE where Title = 'MaxUserAttempts';

    -- 2.b) Get total failed attempts since last successful login
            -- Get Last Successful login date
    Select @LastLogin = LoginDatetime from tblLOG where ID = @ID AND UserName = @UN AND LoginDatetime in (select max(LoginDatetime) from tblLOG where ID = @ID AND UserName = @UN AND Message = 'Success');

            -- Get failed attempts count
    Select @FailedAttempts = count(*) from tblLOG where LoginDatetime > @LastLogin;

    -- 2.c) If failed attempts > maximum allowed attempts, account is locked, else account is not locked.
    If @FailedAttempts < @MaxAttempts
    Begin
        Set @Output = 'Success';
    End
    Else Set @Output = 'User account is locked.';
End

Select @Output;
END
```

Comment: can you post the code for `sp_UserValidation`? Or does it always return `Success`? Apparently the only time when the `@Message` is `Not valid` is when `@ValidUser` is not equal to `Success`.

Comment: [Creating Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx): "We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using **sp_** as a prefix. SQL Server uses the **sp_** prefix to designate system stored procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system procedure."

Comment: sp_UserValidation code has been posted to the main post. Also, thank you for the sp_ prefix recommendation, I will change that naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
Execute sp_UserValidation @ID, @UN, @PW, @ValidUser output;
```

Stored procedures don't return strings.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) is the reference that return values are an integer.  I'm very surprised it doesn't generate a syntax error when you write it.  I suppose this is because `return` is also used in functions that can return any type.

I've always used the return as a status indicator.  In your case, you are passing a variable in and then using it, so it makes sense that it would be an output parameter.

Comment: integers implicitly cast to `varchar` so it will just end up with a string like `0` in the variable. The OP can't actually be doing `RETURN 'Success'` as that would give an invalid cast error.

Comment: @MartinSmith . .  I actually tried the `return 'Success'` on SQL Fiddle and it worked.  Perhaps that is a peculiarity of that environment, but it very much surprised me.

Comment: You tried executing the stored procedure? It is a run time error not compile time.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . No, I was referring to compile time.